# Multiple base vertex per instanced draw

Tags: opengl

I am searching a way to do a glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex but with different base vertex for each instance.

Basically I have to render a lot of cubes (bounding boxes) which have different model space coordinates.
Each cube have its own modelToCamera matrix which is passed via instanced arrays attributes to the vertex shader.

The problem is that I have a list of 16 indices to render, which are the same for each cube, except for their baseVertex part, and I want to render every cube in a single draw call, without having 16 * numberOfCube indices.

So is there a way to change the baseVertex for each instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Furthermore, there's no reason to want to in your case either. If each cube has it's own "model space coordinates" *and* it's own "modelToCamera matrix"... then you have redundant information.

All cubes are similar to one another. The *only* difference between one cube and another is the *transform* of it: scale, rotation, translation. You can take a unit cube and apply a transform to it to turn it into *any other cube.*

Since you're applying a different transform to each cube, then all your cubes could be just the same initial vertices repeated over and over.

However, don't expect this to give you much performance increase; instancing for tiny objects like a cube generally doesn't help much.

Comment: The thing is that I don't do any transformations on the cubes, they are directly created that way, using the bounding box of other mesh. But I guess I can create a matrix that transform a unit cube to the bounding box size, so I wouldn't need to do instanced drawing. Thanks.

Comment: @user2039813: "*I don't do any transformations on the cubes*" Then why are you passing a matrix to them?

Comment: I mean that I don't do any transformations from a generic cube mesh to their model space positions. They are directly created with these positions, once for all. Then I need to apply a transformation from model to camera space, per frame. This matrix is unique per cube because they all have their own transformations from my hierarchical scene graph. But thanks to you advice, I have now created a transformation from a unit cube to the bounding box size, which is then combined with the modelToCamera matrix, and sent to the instanced draw call. So it works now. You helped me a lot :)